# How to make a non deterministic query be deterministic?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have the following Sybase database schema (boiled down to the question-related tables):

```
         ___________         ___________         ________
        | MyEvent   |       | EventKind |       | Record |
        |———————————|       |———————————|       |————————|
        | ID        |    -->| ID        |    -->| ID     |
        | Date      |    |  | Label     |    |  | No     |
        | Amount    |    |  |___________|    |  | Date   |
        | kind_ID   |-FK-^                   |  |________|
        | record_ID |--------FK--------------^
        |___________|
```

I was asked to query a certain period for `Record`s having `MyEvent`s with specified `Label`s (`E2`, `I5`) and sum the `Amount`s of other `MyEvent`s labeled `K0`, `K1` or `K2` if there are any, otherwise that column of the result table should show `0`. The result table should look like this:

**Most important and difficult requirements:**

- select records that contains at least one event labeled E2 or I5, may contain both
- sum the amounts of events labeled `K0`, `K1` and `K2` if a record has those, otherwise return 0

```
 _______________________________________________________________________________
| Record.No | Record.Date | MyEvent.Date | MyEvent.Date | SUM of MyEvent.Amount |
|           |             |      E2      |      I5      |     K0, K1 and K2     |
 ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
| 12345     | 2019-10-01  |     NULL     |  2019-10-10  |        52,20          |
| 23456     | 2018-02-15  |  2018-02-30  |  2018-05-10  |        34,80          | 
| 34567     | 2017-06-26  |     NULL     |  2017-07-04  |            0          | 
| 45678     | 2015-03-17  |  2017-07-04  |     NULL     |       129,10          | 
 ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

I am currently not able to get any result returned, though I am sure there are tons of `Record`s having one of the `MyEvent`s `E2` and `I5` (or both) as well as a lot of them having `MyEvent`s labeled `K0`, `K1` or `K2`.

My current approach is the following, which makes use of `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` but currently has to re-use the subqueries (ugly anyway, but also obviously wrong):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.No AS "Record.No",
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    r.Date AS "Record.Date",
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT FIRST
            MyEvent.Date
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label = 'E2'
    ) THEN NULL
    ELSE (
        SELECT FIRST
            MyEvent.Date
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label = 'E2'
    ) END AS "MyEvent.Date E2",
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT FIRST
            MyEvent.Date
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label = 'I5'
    ) THEN NULL
    ELSE (
        SELECT FIRST
            MyEvent.Date
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label = 'I5'
    ) END AS "MyEvent.Date I5",
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT
            SUM(MyEvent.Amount)
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label IN ('K0', 'K1', 'K2')
    ) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE (
        SELECT
            SUM(MyEvent.Amount)
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            EventKind.Label IN ('K0', 'K1', 'K2')
    ) END AS "Sum of MyEvent.Amount K0, K1 and K2"
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
FROM
    Record r
    INNER JOIN MyEvent e ON e.record_ID = r.ID
    INNER JOIN EventKind k ON k.ID = e.kind_ID
WHERE
    a.clientNo IN (515, 520, 521, 522, 535, 632, 832, 853, 889, 890, 892, 893, 894, 895, 934)
    AND
    a.Date BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
    AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT FIRST
            MyEvent.Date
        FROM
            MyEvent
            INNER JOIN EventKind ON EventKind.ID = MyEvent.kind_ID
        WHERE
            MyEvent.record_ID = r.ID
            AND
            (
                EventKind.Label = 'I5'
                OR
                EventKind.Label = 'E2'
            )
    )
ORDER BY
    r.No ASC
```

Using this query, the first thing I get is a warning, which is already a hint pointing to *something wrong with the query*:

[image: Sybase warning about non deterministic result]

<s>The second thing I get is a `0 rows returned`, unfortunately, which is definitely not the desired output ;-)</s>

The desired output is expected to be 58200 rows having the correct event dates and event sums.

**EDIT**

After having corrected several flaws in the query, I  get the correct amount of results now and all random samples I checked are correct, **but still the warning about the result being non deterministic is showing**.

How can I get rid of that? It makes me feel bad because it implies possibly different outputs for different exectutions, doesn't it? I executed it 5 times so far and the results are equal…

If anyone has suggestions about how to reduce the SQL code, I would love to read them.

Comment: . .  I would suggest that you simplify the query to replicate the issue (by removing unnecessary columns and joins).  Then ask a *new* question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I should do that...

Comment: would also help to know the Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version

Comment: @markp It's SQL Anywhere 16

Comment: a google search returns several hits with basically the same solution as found [here](https://tutel.me/c/dba/questions/11948/when+is+a+result+returned+deterministic+and+when+not); in a nutshell, it appears to be a bothersome 'warning' which doesn't affect the query ... and to eliminate the warning it's recommended to either a) add an `order by` clause or b) wrap the query in a `begin/end` block; do either of these kludges work?

Comment: @markp There is an `ORDER BY` clause already, but I will check out wrapping in `BEGIN` - `END` tomorrow. It's for and at work and that's where I am not at the moment ;-)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` should be `inside` the inner `SELECT FIRST` subquery, that will make the query deterministic

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about SQLAnywhere (let alone this particular 'error') to know if the message could be related to one of the sub-queries (which obviously don't have/need a 'order by') ...

Comment: I guess you need to add `ORDER BY` anywhere you have a `FIRST`. On the other hand, I think the `FIRST`are useless inside an `EXISTS`...